# Jquery slidedown not work properly

Tags: php, jquery, html

i have used jquery to validate a form.i used slideDown().but error message not work properly.but when i use alert it works properly as i want.i redirect the form action to registerphp.php page.it includes registration code.

html code,

```
    <form action="registerphp.php" method="post" id="regfrm" name="regfrm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label >User Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uname" name="uname" >
        </div>                                      
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwds">Passowrd</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwds" name="pwds">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Confirm Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwds2" name="pwds2">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label >Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Phone</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Birth date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="bdate" name="bdate">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>University</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="uni" name="uni">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>GPA</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="gpa" name="gpa" step=".01">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add" name="add">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block btn-md" value="Submit" name="buttonregister" id="buttonregister"></input>
    </form>
```

Jquery code below

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#buttonregister').click(function () {
        var title=$('#title').val();
        var name=$('#name').val();
        var phone=$('#phone').val();


        if(title=="")
        {
            $('#dis').slideDown().html("<span>Please type Title</span>");
            alert('no');
            return false;
        }
        if(name=="")
        {
            $('#dis').slideDown().html("<span>Please type Name</span>");
            alert('no2');
            return false;
        }
        if(!$.isNumeric(phone))
        {
            $('#dis').slideDown().html("<span>Please type Name</span>");
            alert('no3');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

css,

```
#dis
{
    text-align:center;
    height: 25px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color:#46DAFF;
    color:#000;
}
#tex
{
    width:120px;
    float: left;
}
```

help me to solve this problem

Comment: Where is element with id='dis' ? also are you hiding that element with css ?

Comment: dis is id for css file

Comment: yes for css is okay but is there any element on page with that id ? say `<div id='dis'></div>` something like that ?

Comment: no there is no any id 'dis'

Comment: Then you have to add that element on the page. say above the form. copy paste my above comment code and paste it if it works.

Comment: it not works friend

Comment: I thought it works. what is the error can you paste screenshot of the output somewhre ? imgur etc ?

Comment: no error message.nothing happen